# cant publish Web Application to file system with vs 2012 express

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I have tried to publish 3 different web applications to my file system and every time I get  the same error  message :

**"The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.    ASPNETCOMPILER  "**

I have download the Visual Studio 2012 30 Days trial version and it working great but Unfortunately I cant Afford it.

any idea how to fix this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error explains itself: one or more of the paths exceeded 260 characters.

First, shorten your workspace directory (e.g., change from `C:\SomeDir\SomeAnotherDir\Sources\YourProject` to `C:\src\YourProject`).

Also make sure to apply the latest TFS [Update](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/visual-studio-update) on the server, which [stretches the limit to 400 characters](http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/home/news/2012/oct-8/) (in the source control tree, not the workspace directory).

Comment: Thanks. I did short my  workspace directory and it works.
the update is not for the express edition.